# Checkbox always shows true in ReactJS only on production

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, bootstrap-4

So I have very specific issues. I have checkbox with controlled component and it works fine on local machine, but when I push code online, then everything works (check/uncheck), data are ok "0" and "1", but checkbox is always checked. Anyone knows what might be cause of problem?

https://gist.github.com/sasafister/3f6d555432986a74e37f113685720a6d

Here is my code

```
    <input className="float-right" type="checkbox" defaultChecked={course.is_featured} onChange={this.toggleChecked.bind(this, course.id)} />
```

Comment: If it's a controlled input, should be `checked ` instead `defaultChecked`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a controlled input you must have `value/checked` and `onChange` handler. `defaultChecked` is for initial load and not updatable.

```
<input className="float-right" type="checkbox" checked={course.is_featured} onChange={this.toggleChecked.bind(this, course.id)} />
```

Comment: I tried, but it won't work. So locally it works fine, but on production is some kind of problem :/